# Add extra action flag to LogEntry in Django

Tags: python, django, logging, admin

I am registering a custom Log Entry model to django admin Panel.
This is the code:

```
class CustomLogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "action_time",
        "user",
        "content_type",
        "shortIds",
        "object_repr",
        "action_flag",
        "shortMessage",
    ]

    def shortIds(self, obj):
        return Truncator(obj.object_id).chars(30)

    shortIds.short_description = "Object ID"

    def shortMessage(self, obj):
        return Truncator(obj.change_message).chars(60)

    shortMessage.short_description = "Change Message"

    # list filter
    list_filter = ["action_time", "user", "content_type"]

    # search
    search_fields = ["user__username", "object_repr"]


admin.site.register(LogEntry, CustomLogEntryAdmin)
```

there are 3 default action flags of LogEntry

```
ADDITION: int
CHANGE: int
DELETION: int
```

I want to add a 4th action flag called 'VIEW'. How do I do it?